# Fixing bottom D key in piano

Tags: piano, key, repair

So there was some buzzing in some keys because of an object that fell inside the piano. While I was removing the object I’m afraid that I ruined the very bottom D key action. I guess I can live without its too complicated to fix but if it’s something that can be fixed at home might as well give it a shot. There seems to be like a thin string that came loose within the action for that key. I’m looking at diagrams trying to identify the pieces I’m seeing and comparing their behavior with the other (working) keys. Basically now when I hit the broken key, what appears to be the main action rail moves back instead of up to lift the hammer, if I do it strongly the hammer actually works and hits the string but if I gently hit the key it won’t work at all. Is this loose string the spring rail? Does that keep the rail from moving back? Can this be fixed at home or do I need a pro?

Comment: Is it a string or a stiff wire spring?  In any event, it is not the spring rail, which is a wooden rail that runs across the entire action and holds one end of each of 88 springs (or however many keys the piano has).

Comment: It is a very thin wire that is loose and not a string perse

Comment: I looked at some piano actions on YouTube, and it seems that more modern ones have dispensed with the spring rail and its associated springs entirely, using gravity instead.  How old is this piano?

Comment: Maybe a picture would help?

Comment: I am not an expert, but pianos are very delicate and very expensive. In those circumstances, my general advice is "if you have to ask if you need a pro, you do indeed need a pro".

Comment: Hey guys thank you so much for your help! I was starting to make a little video for everyone's reference but while making it I saw the problem a bit better enough to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old piano from the 50s, an Estey...I still don't know the names of each part to be able to accurately describe what was going on since all the vidual diagrams I've seen online seem somewhat different from each other and I can't really see the hammer from that inside the piano accurately but the wire that was loose basically had to be pushed back so it fell right between an indentation behind the action mechanism. Once there that brought the hammer action into place. These hammers are truly marvelous little mechanic wonders!